# Labeling tuple variables in print statement

Tags: python, printing, tuples

I'm having a bit of a formatting problem, and I'm hoping you can help. Basically, my program gives me a list of tuples that I'd like to print on each line. This part is easy, however for readability, I want to label each element in the tuples in the print statements, like so:

```
[(n=0, a=175, t=94, g=292, c=39),
(n=0, a=90, t=33, g=166, c=248),
(n=0, a=121, t=159, g=155, c=165)]
```

Here are the relevant parts of my code, thus far.

```
my_results = zip(results_n, results_a, results_t, results_c, results_g)
#my_results returns a list of tuples

from pprint import pprint
#pprint(my_results, depth=5)
#returns [(0, 175, 94, 292, 39),
#(0, 90, 33, 166, 248),
#(0, 121, 159, 155, 165)]

toople = (0, 175, 94, 292, 39)
(n, a, t, g, c) = toople
#maybe unpacking the tuple will help in some way?
```

As you can see, the only part I can't figure out how to do is print my tuples with the extra "n=", "a=", ... bits. How might I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string formatting. The `*` unpacks each element in the `result` and sends it as a separate argument to `format()`, which needs an argument for each item rather than a `tuple` containing all the arguments.

```
for result in my_results:
    print('n={}, a={}, t={}, g={}, c={}'.format(*result))
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional way to do it:

```
# data for testing
combos = [(0, 175, 94, 292, 39),
          (0, 90,  33, 166, 248),
          (0, 121, 159,155, 165)]
results_n, results_a, results_t, results_c, results_g = zip(*combos)

labels = 'n={}', 'a={}', 't={}', 'g={}', 'c={}'
my_results = '\n'.join((', '.join(f.format(v) for f, v in zip(labels, row))
        for row in zip(results_n, results_a, results_t, results_c, results_g)))
print(my_results)
```

Output:

```
n=0, a=175, t=94, g=292, c=39
n=0, a=90, t=33, g=166, c=248
n=0, a=121, t=159, g=155, c=165
```